# How can I change the partitionKey for a Dynamo table?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

```
 this.table = new dynamodb.Table(this, `${stackName}-${id}`, {
      tableName: `${stackName}-${id}`,
      partitionKey: { name: 'message_id', type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING },
      sortKey: { name: 'entityId', type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING },
      billingMode: dynamodb.BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST,
      tableClass: dynamodb.TableClass.STANDARD,
      stream: dynamodb.StreamViewType.NEW_IMAGE,
      timeToLiveAttribute: 'ttl',
      removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
    });
```

But I need to change that `partitionKey` from `message_id` to `messageId`. Is there any way to do this programmatically? Or do I have to manually delete the table in every environment? This hasn't been deployed to production yet but it has been deployed to dev env.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to delete and recreate the table to change the name of the partition key and/or sort key.

Heck, you can't even change the value of the PK of a record in DDB.

Comment: Figured as much. Spoiled by Flyway I guess.